# SQL to store last transaction date

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to populate a column which will store the previous transaction date if any new row is inserted.

I'm looking for something like this

```
Customer ID | first txn date | txn date  | last txn date | prev txn dt
   1        |   01-Jun-20    | 01-Jun-20 | 27-Sep-21     | null
   1        |   01-Jun-20    | 24-Dec-20 | 27-Sep-21     | 01-Jun-20
   1        |   01-Jun-20    | 20-Sep-21 | 27-Sep-21     | 24-Dec-20
   1        |   01-Jun-20    | 27-Sep-21 | 27-Sep-21     | 20-Sep-21
```

Comment: If any new "column" is inserted? Surely you mean "row", right? I would think this would be done as part of the routine/logic/code/script that performs the insert to then also perform the update.

Answer (score 0):

in mysql 8+ :

```
select * 
  , MIN(txndate) over (partition by CustomerID) firsttxndate
  , MAX(txndate) over (partition by CustomerID) lasttxndate
  , LAG(txndate) over (partition by customerID order by txndate) as prvtxndate
from table
```